# Достать с сайта разделы

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Достаю информацию с сайта. Возникла проблема, у меня категории все находятся под разным аттрибутами. Например, категория другие находится под тегом a href="/other/" class="other_sport-tag..."
а категория футбол под a href="/football/" class="wwcwan...". Можно ли как-то достать все категории сразу?
[image: введите сюда описание]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они все лежат в одном `div`'е, поэтому находим этот `div` и из него достаём все `a`

```
soup.find("div", class_ = "news-item__content rbhpoqt").find_all("a")
```